# Default activity from dynamic-feature

Tags: android, architecture, dynamic-feature-module

We are restructuring our app, so we basically transformed our application modules into dynamic-feature. Now we have all our code on our dynamic-feature and the application modules is like a wrapper in order to run the dynamic-feature.

The problem we are facing is that we cannot have a dynamic-feature Activity as default launcher activity. Is there any workaround we can do in order to be able to run the app with the default launcher activity?

Answer (score 1):

This is just my assumption but you cannot place your default launcher activity into your dynamic feature module. This is because when the application starts, app module is loaded but DFM may not be available unless it is delivered on install-time.

Posting even a portion of your source code may help others understand your situation better so I suggest that you do that if you can.

Comment: I don't think that the source code could help as it is more of an architectural problem. I was wondering if there was any workarounds. One idea I had was to start an empty activity from the application module and launch the dynamic-feature activity as soon as it's available.

Comment: > One idea I had was to start an empty activity from the application module and launch the dynamic-feature activity as soon as it's available. I think it will work!